# Run Timer for first time and resume timer for second time

Tags: iphone

Declared variable in m file.

```
BOOL isFirstTime;
```

I want that if play button is pressed the very first time then it should toggle to pause button and check the function `isFirstTime` then it should start the timer and execute the `displayviewsAction` method and if the pause button is resumed to play back then it should check again the function `isFirstTime` or second time and if the hit is for the second time then it should resume timer.

```
-(void)playpauseAction:(id)sender {
if ([audioPlayer isPlaying]){         
   [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Play Icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
   [audioPlayer pause];
   [self pauseTimer];
} else {
  [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [audioPlayer play];
  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(AfterOneSecondsFuction) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
        }         
}
-(void)pauseTimer{
pauseStart = [[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0] retain];
previousFireDate = [[timer fireDate] retain];
[timer setFireDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
}
 -(void)resumeTimer{
float pauseTime = -1*[pauseStart timeIntervalSinceNow];
[timer setFireDate:[previousFireDate initWithTimeInterval:pauseTime sinceDate:previousFireDate]];
[pauseStart release];
[previousFireDate release];    
}
-(void)AfterOneSecondsFuction
{
if(!isFirstTime)
{
 isFirstTime=YES;
 return;
 self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:11.0
                                                  target:self
                                                selector:@selector(displayviewsAction:)
                                                userInfo:nil
                                                repeats:NO];

} else if (!isFirstTime){
  isFirstTime=NO;
  return;
  [self resumeTimer]; 

     }
}    

- (void)displayviewsAction:(id)sender
{  
  First *firstController = [[First alloc] init];
firstController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
CATransition *transitionAnimation = [CATransition animation];   
[transitionAnimation setDuration:1];
[transitionAnimation setType:kCATransitionFade];
[transitionAnimation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction     functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn]];
[self.view.layer addAnimation:transitionAnimation forKey:kCATransitionFade];
[self.view addSubview:firstController.view];
[self.view addSubview:toolbar];
[firstController release];   
}

-(void)Second 
{
 Second *secondController = [[Second alloc] init];
secondController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
CATransition *transitionAnimation = [CATransition animation];
[transitionAnimation setDuration:1];
[transitionAnimation setType:kCATransitionReveal];
[transitionAnimation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn]];
[self.view.layer addAnimation:transitionAnimation forKey:kCATransitionReveal];
[self.view addSubview:secondController.view]; 
[self.view addSubview:toolbar];
[secondController release];
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:27 target:self selector:@selector(Third) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
 }
```

Looks like when play is pressed first it is only toggling to pause button not checking the function `isFirstTime` or not and not starting the timer and executing displayviewsaction.

If anyone can tell why it is not happening and what i m doing wrong.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

```
BOOL isFirstTime

//Somewhere where the object is set up, isFirstTime should be set to YES


- (void)playpauseAction:(id)sender {

//When the button is pressed

if(isFirstTime) {

//Load the sound file
//Start playing the sound
//Start view controller timers
//Change the button image to paused
isFirstTime = FALSE;

}

else {

//The button has already been pressed

if ([audioPlayer isPlaying]) {

//If the sound is playing

//Stop playing the sound
//Stop view controller timers
//Change the button image to playing

}

else {

//Resume playing the sound
//Start view controller timers
//Change the button image to paused

}

}


}
```

Comment: all i m trying to is that you have one play button which will toggle to pause button when it is pressed it will play audio file and start the timer and start loading view controllers at different time intervals one after the other now when pause button is pressed it should pause the timer so that view controllers won't load further and when pause button is pressed again to resume it should resume timer and start loading view controllers from that point.

Comment: Ok cool, so assuming that your are just asking about how to implement the button, not the way that the view controllers switch, I have updated the answer;

Comment: By the way I'm not sure by what you mean "the function isFirstTime", you don't have a method 'isFirstTime' as you have no reference to it, do you mean the BOOL isFirstTime, as that is a pointer/iVar, not a method.

Comment: Yes it is BOOL isFirstTime as a variable and i have not worked with BOOL before and how you set it to YES

Comment: A BOOL, or boolean, is the most primitive data type, being a 1 or 0 for YES/NO or TRUE/FALSE, which are macros in iOS. So to answer you question all you do is `isFirstTime = YES`.